# why --disable-web-security doesn't function on chromium-based browsers?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, same-origin-policy

I'm looking to perform cross-domain requests on my localhost in developer mode. I work on Opera. So I used the following command to disable web security since Opera is based on Chromium:

```
cd c:\Program Files\Opera\
launcher.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\nocorsbrowserdata"
```

according to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/7543678/where-to-disable-cross-network-protection-in-opera?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc). It did open a new instance of Opera for me with the following message:**You are using an unsupporting command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer** to certify that web security has been disabled. But when I try to perform a cross-domain request, I get `CORS` related errors. So I tried disabling web security on Chrome thinking it was a browser issue using the following command:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

It gave me the same message as in Opera but I still didn't get there to perform cross-domain queries. I still don't understand because I was certified on several stackoverflow questions that I could make cross-site requests by disabling web security.

Comment: have you checked newer answers, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442160/2864275 ?

Comment: Thanks, it works but should I use `--disable-site-isolation-trials` for other Chromium based browsers like Opera?